# JAXB: What is the best way to write a method which parses Date of different formats from an XML file

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

So there is a way to parse Date from XML using XmlAdapter.
 `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)`. 
But as far as I know this allows to parse Date of hardcoded format. Is there a way to pass desirable Date Format at runtime to the Adapter? Or any other way to parse Date of different formats from XML.

Comment: You can apply `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` at field level, so use difernent classes for diferent fields.  Or do you mean select the format at runtime to unmarshal the same mapped class?

Comment: @areus I want it to be just one class for all the formats that I want to use, since creating different class for every date format seems kinda awkward.

Comment: There can only be one instance of the adapter during an unmarshall operation. So if the same XML have diferent fields that require diferent formats, it can't be done. It would work if during the unmarshall there is only one format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when you declare a `XmlAdapter` with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`, JAXB creates an instance of this adapter using the empty constructor to use it during the marshall or unmarshall operations.

But the `Unmarshaller` and `Marshaller` interfaces have a method to provide an instance of the adapter.

You could provide an alternate constructor to your `DateAdapter` with a parameter for the format you want to use, and also declare a DEFAULT_FORMAT. Something like this:

```
private String format;

public DateAdapter() {
    this(DEFAULT_FORMAT);
}

public DateAdapter(String format) {
    this.format = format;
}
```

And when you need to unmarshall:

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setAdapter(DateAdapter.class, new DateAdapter(someFormat));
Object o1 = unmarshaller.unmarshal(....);

unmarshaller.setAdapter(DateAdapter.class, new DateAdapter(otherFormat));
Object o2 = unmarshaller.unmarshal(....);
```